# Write an assembly code that sorts the following numbers on the stack memory: 2, 34, 3, 12, 8

Tags: sorting, assembly, atmega, atmel

**EDIT:** Initially, I was under the impression I was using x86, but I am not. I do not know what version of assembly (if that's actually what it's called) I am using. Just that when I open atmel my professor has us select ATMega328p.

This is a question I'm currently trying to solve. I'm a non-cs major that is hopeless when it comes to programming in assembly, and I just want to get through the rest of the semester. I am using ATMega328p. I have found some sorting algorithms on the internet ( http://www.miguelcasillas.com/?p=340 ) and ( https://github.com/oc-cs360/s2014/blob/master/lc3/bubblesort.asm ) but I'm not sure how to utilize them to accomplish this. Any tips on what to modify/if these are even applicable to my situation are appreciated.

For reference, the first part of the assignment asked me to reverse a 100-element array stored in the memory, using the stack. The code I produced for this was:

```
ldi r16, low(RAMEND)
out spl, r16
ldi r16, high(RAMEND)
out sph, r16

ldi r17, 0
ldi zl, low(0x0100)
ldi zh, high(0x0100)
lpm

ldi r17, 100
ldi xl, low(0x0150)
ldi xh, high(0x0150)
lpm

loop:
cpi r17, 100
brge reverse
push r17
st z+, r17
inc r17
jmp loop

reverse:
cpi r17, 1
brlt done
pop r18
st z+, r18
dec r17
jmp reverse

done:
ret
```

In that instance, we weren't given any specific values so a loop was used. I'm assuming for this question the solutions begins something like:

```
ldi r16, low(RAMEND)
out spl, r16
ldi r16, high(RAMEND)
out sph, r16

ldi r16, 2
sts 0x0100, r16
ldi r16, 32
sts 0x0101, r16
ldi r16, 3
sts 0x0102, r16
ldi r16, 12
sts 0x0103, r16
ldi r16, 8
sts 0x0104, r16
```

But afterwards, once I have to access the RAM and begin sorting/comparing the values I become lost.

Comment: That's not x86; atmega doesn't make any x86 chips.  The syntax is definitely not x86 either.

Comment: Peter, do you have any idea what it is then? I was told by one of my peers that it was, I guess they were misinformed.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the AVR Assembly instuction set. See [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf)
and you can find the specific instructions for the ATmega328p in the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf) at chapter 37. (Can't add this as comment yet..)

What you should do is push the first element on the stack, then decrease the stack pointer(seems to be part of the push operation, same for pop). And go on untill everything from the array is on the stack. Then reverse this operation by pulling the data from the stack (increase stackpointer here) and go on untill the stack is empty. If this is done the array should be reversed.